# Is bimonthly or bi-monthly correct spelling

Tags: spelling

Is bimonthly or bi-monthly correct?

In

> http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bi-monthly?s=t

I can find both in the examples.

Comment: The non-hyphenated version is preferred, but both are used routinely. An ngram is the next comment in the logical series:

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a trivial matter in the sense that no one will fault you if you spell it *bi-monthly* or *bimonthly*. Anyway, the entry is under **bimonthly** at dictionary.com and Merriam-Webster [bimonthly](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bi-monthly). The examples given at dictionary.com are from works that are at least one hundred years old. If we look at some search results, we see that *bimonthly* is more popular.

[image]

So all in all, I would write *bimonthly*.